# How to store the values of different buttons separately in textbox on click event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic, textbox

I am working on a attendance module and this is the prototype of the code, but I have some errors.

As you can see there are dynamically generated buttons and they change colour on click event. I am also storing the value of the buttons in textboxes on click as I have to handle this data on backend with PhP, the error is that when I turn a button to green it's value goes into a textbox and when again i turn it red same value goes into another textbox also, which I don't want. So please help me in solving this problem by reducing the duplicacy of data or by providing a code of a different submit button which when clicked checks the color of all the buttons and stores the values in different textboxes respectively, one for red and one for green. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button click event</title>
    </head>
  <body>

  <?php
  for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
    ?>
    <button class="btnColorChange" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="background-color:#FF0000"><?php echo $i; ?></button>
    <?php
  }
  ?>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="textbox1" value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="textbox2" value=""/><br><br>
  </div>

  <script>
  $(".btnColorChange").click(function(){
    xyz = this.id
    if(this.clicked){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
      const tb=document.querySelector("#textbox1");
      tb.value=tb.value+","+xyz;
      console.log(xyz)
      this.clicked  = false;
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#008000');
      const tb2=document.querySelector("#textbox2");
      tb2.value=tb2.value+","+xyz;
      console.log(xyz)
      this.clicked  = true;
    }
  });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the below statement is wrong:

> there are dynamically generated buttons...

When talking about "dynamic" elements, we talk about element that were not existing on page load. It's not the case here, since they were created before page load, on the server-side. Using a loop does not make them "dynamic".

---

To store clicked/unclicked ids, I suggest you to use some arrays for this.

As I understand it, you want all the *"clicked"* and *"unclicked"* ids separately.
The *"never clicked"* are ignored.

Using two arrays, you can store ids in the relevant group... And even sort them (optionnally).

And you can send those arrays straight to your backend... So the `input` elements would now be just for testing purposes.

See comments in code:

```js
// Arrays to store ids
var clicked = [],
    unclicked = [];

$(".btnColorChange").on("click",function(){
  // useful for this demo
  console.clear();

  // Get the clicked element id
  var this_id = this.id;
  console.log("Clicked id: "+this_id);

  // Toggle the classes (button colors)
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked unclicked");

  // Check if in array
  var in_clicked = $.inArray(this_id,clicked);
  var in_unclicked = $.inArray(this_id,unclicked);
  //console.log(in_clicked+" "+in_unclicked)

  // If clicked
  if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
    if(in_clicked==-1){
      clicked.push(this_id);
      clicked.sort();
    }
    if(in_unclicked>-1){
      unclicked.splice(in_unclicked,1);
    }
  }

  // If unclicked
  if($(this).hasClass("unclicked")){
    if(in_unclicked==-1){
      unclicked.push(this_id);
      unclicked.sort();
    }
    if(in_clicked>-1){
      clicked.splice(in_clicked,1);
    }
  }

  // Show arrays content in console
  console.log(clicked);
  console.log(unclicked);

  // Show the ids in inputs as a coma separated string
  $("#textbox1").val(clicked.join(","));
  $("#textbox2").val(unclicked.join(","));
});
```

```css
.unclicked{
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.clicked{
  background-color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btnColorChange unclicked" id="1">1</button>
<button class="btnColorChange unclicked" id="2">2</button>
<button class="btnColorChange unclicked" id="3">3</button>
<button class="btnColorChange unclicked" id="4">4</button>
<button class="btnColorChange unclicked" id="5">5</button>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="textbox1" value=""/><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="textbox2" value=""/><br><br>
</div>
```

*Please run the snippet in full page mode, because of the console logs.*

For more reading, the below demo uses the following methods:

- [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
- [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

You certainly noticed that I used two CSS rules for the button colors, instead of inline style attributes.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XGaXmY?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well, you want for example the Button to handle updates of textbox1 on first click and update textbox2 on second click. You could do this.

```
$(".btnColorChange").on("click", function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var id = btn.attr("id");

    if(btn.hasClass('clicked')){
        var textboxselected = $("#textbox1");
        var backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        btn.removeClass('clicked');
    }else{
        var textboxselected = $("#textbox2");
        var backgroundColor = "#008000";
        btn.addClass('clicked');
    }
    btn.css("background-color", backgroundColor);
    textboxselected.val(textboxselected.val()+id);
});
```

Suppose you want to update same textbox

```
$(".btnColorChange").on("click", function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var id = btn.attr("id");
    var textvalue = $("#textbox1").val();

    if(btn.hasClass('clicked')){
        var backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        btn.removeClass('clicked');
    }else{
        var backgroundColor = "#008000";
        btn.addClass('clicked');
    }
    btn.css("background-color", backgroundColor);
    $("#textbox1").val(textvalue);
});
```

Its untested but hopes it works for you.

Comment: The "main" issue was *«duplicated ids»* in both inputs... Your answer does not answer that.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate ids. `<input type="text" name="text1" id="textbox1" value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="textbox2" value=""/><br><br>`

Comment: *«problem by reducing the duplicacy of data [...] stores the values in different textboxes respectively, one for red and one for green.»*